# Numpy array reshape customization python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an np array `n` and the shape is (250,250). after that I converted (final array `w`)it into (250,250,3) because I need to do some operation on it.

is it possible to convert the shape of `w` to `(250,250)`?

thanks in advance.
I tried some `reshaping` operation of Numpy but it does not work!

[Numpy reshaping array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824566/numpy-reshaping-array)

[Comparing two NumPy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

[Numpy reshaping array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824566/numpy-reshaping-array)

Comment: Since you have no code posted it is difficult to understand what you want to do concretely. But you can use w[;,:,0] to get one array of shape (250,250) and w[;,:,1] to get another one and for w[;,:,2] a third one. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.reshape`

> Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.

so this is not right to convert array with shape of `(250,250,3)` into array with shape of `(250,250)` as 1st does have 187500 cells and 2nd does have 62500 cells.

You probably should use slicing, consider following example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]]])  # has shape (2,2,2)
arr2 = arr[:,:,0]  # get certain cross-section, check what will happend if you use 1 inplace of 0 and 2 inplace of 0
print("arr2")
print(arr2)
print("arr2.shape",arr2.shape)
```

output

```
arr2
[[0 2]
 [4 6]]
arr2.shape (2, 2)
```